# c++ Service is stopping with error "this application has requested the runtime to terminate it an unusual way"

Tags: c++, service, windows-xp

I have a c++ NTservice which is being accessed by SAP modules through rfc calls. Now this service is getting stopped with a message that "this application has requested the runtime to terminate it an unusual way" and then showing some IE script error that points to url "res://C:\WINDOWS\System32\mmcndmgr.dll/views.htm"   -- I am getting this error very rarely and unexpectedly.

I have no clue why this error is coming, please anyone can guide me about the details and how to correct it if possible

(Windows xp, service is created in MSVC 2005)

Thanks,
Anil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message (at least usually) means you had an uncaught exception. You could start by adding a `try`/`catch(std::exception const &e)`/`catch(...)` to your ServiceMain, in an attempt at catching the exception and if it is a derivative of `std::exception`, printing out its `what()` to see what it has to say for itself...

Comment: Or a segmentation fault. Or a FPE. Or any number of things!

Comment: While it can be other things, it's frequently enough an uncaught exception that it's typically what you want to try first. When/if that fails 1) the exception handling code is still good to have there, and 2) you have to get into more difficult things...

Comment: Your practical logic is sound. I'd love to see the stats, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's the very unhelpful message that displays when your executable has crashed. Almost anything could be wrong.

Run your executable through a debugger and wait for the problem to occur. You can then try to find out more information about it.

In particular I'd check the service's documentation and make sure that your SAP modules are using the RFC calls correctly.

Comment: It should be enough to register a post mortem debugger(windbg /I). Running a service in the debugger can be quite a problem.

Comment: @mkaes: You don't *have* to run it as a service. Good idea, though.